# how to show json data from web service

Tags: javascript, json

I have that link http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Andorra+la+Vella that shows on the browser a json with all the values, so I need to pick only the wind, and the temp, but I don't know how to extract it, how to do that?

I thougt in add a callback after "Andorra+la+Vella"&callback=myFunction

And develop a code on javascript to get the values that I need, but I do it and something goes wrong, that's a simple test to try this little application and then i add it to my web:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test tiempo andorra</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showTime(obj) {
        var dadIp=document.getElementById('time');
        dadIp.innerHTML+=obj.sunset.wind.speed;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="time">
    <h1>Test of Time in Andorra</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Andorra+la+Vella&callback=showTime"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your JavaScript error console.

> ```
>  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wind' of undefined
> ```

Then look at the JSON source.

`obj.sunset` doesn't exist. `obj.sys.sunset` does.

`obj.sunset.wind` doesn't exist. `obj.wind` does.

See [a live example](http://jsbin.com/lisupazo/1/edit?html,output) when the correct object paths are used.

Comment: Thanks, in 5 minutes I accept that answer, it goes correctly :D

Comment: so, this question is closed but, and how to show the array [] into the json? because it cannot be tracted as an object, so returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

This way for example:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" )
;
```

In case if you need parse DateTime I advise to use moment.js library.

Comment: The OP doesn't have unparsed JSON in a string. They have parsed JSONP in an object.